# Highcharts line chart - incorrect point ordering - boost module

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-boost

### Issue

We are currently implementing a highcharts graph for large datasets that will require the boost module for performance reasons. However, on enabling the boost module we have encountered an intermittent issue that is proving challenging to consistently reproduce and isolate.

Because I am not able to replicate this I cannot create a jsfiddle as of yet. Does anyone have any idea how to isolate and fix this?

The graph should look like this:

Expected graph

[image]

But occasionally does this:

Actual graph

[image]

This has also happened on another occasion whilst manually testing with different data:

With different data

[image]

It has been observed on

- Chrome 70.0.3538.67
- IE 11.345.17134.0
- Highcharts JS & Boost module v6.1.4

### Input data

Sample of the type of data:

```
{
        "label": "2018-04-19T15:17:02",
        "value": "1"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-19T15:17:05",
        "value": "9620035.36877074"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-19T15:17:59",
        "value": "9583104.14689662"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-19T15:18:46",
        "value": "9604094.84064805"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-19T15:20:17",
        "value": "9571679.9536289"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-20T08:18:24",
        "value": "7902991.39771514"
    }
```

Or:

```
{
        "label": "2018-04-19T15:17:59",
        "value": "1.4132e-007"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-19T15:18:46",
        "value": "1.41434e-007"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-19T15:20:17",
        "value": "1.41355e-007"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-20T08:18:24",
        "value": "1.40532e-007"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-20T08:20:35",
        "value": "1.40928e-007"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-20T08:23:51",
        "value": "1.4078e-007"
    }, {
        "label": "2018-04-20T08:24:39",
        "value": "1.40901e-007"
    }
```

### Graph config

```
{
"chart": {
    "type": "line",
    "zoomType": "x",
    "panning": true,
    "panKey": "shift"
},
"boost": {
    "usePreallocated": false
},
  ...
  y-axis label customisation
  title
  exporting
  etc
  ...
"series": [{
    "showInLegend": false,
    "name": "",
    "data": []
}],
}
```

### Update mechanism

When the HTTP response comes back the following is called on the graph instance:

```
graphToUpdate.series[0].setData(parsedData, true, true, false);
```

Comment: It seems like a bug for me. Try to reproduce it then you can report it as a new issue on Highcharts Github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues.

Comment: Reproduction that is concise and reproducible is one of the issues. Because it is so intermittent i cannot isolate the cause. Any ideas what could be causing it would be useful.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Or this issue only occurs on Chrome?

Comment: My colleague had come across it on IE 11 during the initial review. I'll get the exact version and update the post.

Comment: Not sure if it is related but if `usePreallocated: true` on much larger sets, zooming in using the graph sometimes draws a line from the first data point to the last. This seems like a different issue to me.